Error 'undefined symbol: _PyUnicode_Ready' after Ubuntu update
I'm using a computer cluster, where all machines are running Ubuntu 24.04 after an update, while the machine I use to access the cluster is running Ubuntu 22.04. The cluster runs with SLURM. In particular, I use a custom Python package with a custom Cython *.so package.
Since the machines were updated, I get the error undefined symbol: _PyUnicode_Ready coming from the Cython package. I read online that this may come from the Python versions not matching and something with changes in later versions of Python (?, not sure about this one, actually), but I checked and the system says using python --version that I am indeed using Python 3.10 and to me this means that when I run the Cython build command I should also be compiling with Python 3.10.
Since I'm neither a superuser nor able to upgrade or install packages/libs etc. myself, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require any of these things to work.
Any help is appreciated :)

You probably just need to force a rebuild when you run the Cython build command. Possibly by using -f as an argument, or by deleting cached intermediate files. (Depends a bit on what the command is)

As an aside - the Cython .so should be built with a version tag - something like *.cpython-310.so. This should prevent it being loaded into incompatible versions of Python. So if any part of your build process involves removing that tag, you're making things worse for your self

Hi DavidW, thanks for your help! Before I had the chance to try your advice I did something else: I logged in into a computer of the network with Ubuntu 24.04 and compiled the Cython package there. It actually seems to work, so I don't know what the issue then was (maybe something with dependencies ?). In that case I probably should ask my IT support to update my machine to the newer version. But in any case, thanks for your comment :)
